# How to detect black colour in a video cam using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, hsv, color-detection

I need to detect black objects in a real time video. I got a code in the internet for detecting blue objects. So I changed the upper and lower hsv value according to bgr colour code(am not clear about how to convert bgr to hsv), But its not detecting the black object in the video.the code am using blue colour detection is:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np  

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  

while(1):        
    _, frame = cap.read()  
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
    lower_red = np.array([110,50,50]) 
    upper_red = np.array([130,255,255]) 
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask) 
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame) 
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask) 
    cv2.imshow('res',res) 
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27: 
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cap.release()
```

the output for blue color is:
original image:
[image: blue]

[image: masked blue]

[image: blue detection]

The code I'm using for black is:`

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np  

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):        
    _, frame = cap.read()  
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
    lower_red = np.array([0,0,0]) 
    upper_red = np.array([0,0,0]) 
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask) 
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame) 
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask) 
    cv2.imshow('res',res)  
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27: 
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cap.release()
```

Result:
[image: original image]

[image: masked black]

[image: result]

Nothing is displayed in the result of black. I think the problem is in the hsv conversion but am not sure. And in the detected blue image is not at all accurate it result in noise. How to achieve black detection and reduce noise?.

Comment: Have a little read about how HSV works https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV and realise black will show up with low saturation (because it isn't a vivid colour) and low `value` because it is not bright. Then change your ranges and for heaven's sake change the names of your variables to give future maintenance engineers a chance. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to detect black would be to do a binary threshold in greyscale. Black pixel values will always have a very low value, so therefore it would be easier to do this in a 1 channel image instead of a 3 channel. I would recommend:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 15, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

change the value of 15 until you get reasonable results. Lower value would result in preserving only darker pixels. If you wanted to extract the location of the pixels you could also get the contours i.e.

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

and then draw the contour back onto the original frame with:

```
frame = cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1,(0,0,255),3)
```

Alternatively, you might find it easier to invert the image first so that you are trying to extract white pixels. This could lead to less confusion with the pixels you want to extract being similar to the mask pixel (0). You could do this simple with numpy subtraction, then set your thresh value to a very high value i.e:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255-gray
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
frame = cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1,(0,0,255),3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
black= np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)

grayScale= np.array([0, 0, 29], np.uint8)
```

Valor (29) depends of how much "brightness" you want.
[This page](http://colorizer.org/) is where you can test your color ranges